# Enable AJAX request with JQUERY for PHP in App engine

Tags: php, ajax, google-app-engine

I need to make request to PHP from Javascript in App engine.

```
 $.ajax({
  url: '../php/info.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  success:function(data) {
   //Do stuff with info from PHP (data)
  },
  error: function(error){
   console.log(error);
  }
});
```

In local this works fine but in App engine the next error appear in console

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Some people say add extension = "curl.so" inside php.ini but is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this has nothing to do with App Engine, per se.  This ajax call is done from the client (browser).  You are sending a `POST`, so most likely the `POST` data you are sending is malformed, or not compatible with the data expected in the backend.  So:

1) What does your `POST` data look like?

2) What does the function handling `../php/info.php` in the backend (app engine) look like?

Comment: This ajax doesnt send anything it only request information because ../php/info.php use $_SESSION['id_user'] to create a navigation bar for especific user. The output it is done through echo json_encode($data);

Comment: and $data looks like "<ul><li>This is the first option</li>.....<li>This is the last option</li> </ul>"  This works fine in local.

Comment: GAEfan do you mean extension = "curl.so" is not necessary in AJAX request from Javascript?

Comment: I made a fool proof and you are rigth the problem is my connection to the database. I made something wrong with Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There can be another reason where your JSON string is incorrect. Try:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(obj.name);
```

Comment: Yes, if the app engine backend is returning a JSON object, that is how to parse.  But, this would give a browser javascript error, not a 500 on the GAE backend.